# what is the code to create a table in sql only at first run of project?

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp, jdbc

hello everyone,

I want to create a web application using jsp,servlet and jdbc etc.

It simply create a table of name student,contains various field as information about student in database and different page perform different query tasks .

The problem is that I want to create a war file to distribute this app to my client.

When I write a sql query to create a table in my jsp page , it tries to create a new table every time whenever I run this project.

Here i want that it creates a table only when the user run this first time.So that when I distribute the war file to my client ,on the first run it create a student name table and perform the required query and for the future run it only perform other query but not create a table again.

I need your valuable guidance and overview for solving this problem.Any type of help will be appreciated.
    "thanks"

Comment: I believe you normally register a class on deploy or startup that runs a query to create the tables of the form `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @Elliott, `IF NOT EXISTS` is **not** valid in `Oracle`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB 1. it is a comment (and not an answer) and 2. are you certain OP is actually using the Oracle RDBMS? 3. What version? 4. How do you know?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, 1. I know it's a comment,so I replied to your comment. 2. The `Oracle` tag in the question is the only way to be certain about the `RDBMS` product. 3. Version is not much important in this question.I believe till `12c`, `IF NOT EXISTS` is not in `Oracle`. 4. I know what I see and mentioned by OP.

Comment: You should be looking into a schema management tool like Liquibase or Flyway

Answer (score 1):

In `Oracle`, the workaround is to wrap it in an anonymous `BEGIN-END` block. The `EXCEPTION` block would simply allow the `table already exists error`.

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE...

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE = -955 THEN
        NULL; -- ignore the ORA-00955 error
      ELSE
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END; 
/
```

This is one way preferably. Another way would be to manually check if the table exists or not in the `data dictionary` view `dba_tables`.

```
SELECT count(*) 
   INTO variable_count 
  FROM dba_tables 
 WHERE table_name = 'table_name';
```

So,

```
IF variable_count = 0 THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE TABLE ...
```